# NServiceBus is not installing RavenDB with RunMeFirst.bat

Tags: installation, nservicebus, ravendb

We are attempting to setup 3.2.7 on a test machine as a service using Production integration.  Raven DB will not download & install.

I've tried NServiceBus.Host.exe /installInfrastructure.  I've tried NServiceBus.Host32.exe /installInfrastructure.  No luck what so ever.

It looks as though the machine isn't pulling down the RavenDB binaries.

I've successfully installed on several dev machines running Win 7 Pro 64/32.

(I meant to post this question yesterday since I've been fighting this issue since then but just as I posted it I discovered the issue - see answer below)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To Andres & Udi - The installer is looking to see if ANYTHING is running on 8080 and if something is then it won't even download RavenDB. Would it be possible to instead check to see if an instance of RavenDB is running on the server.

We had another web service running on that port and just changed it's port.  Then RavenDB installed just fine.  While this is outlined on the website : http://docs.particular.net/nservicebus/ravendb/installation

It would have been GREAT if the installer could have said "port 8080 in use, not installing RavenDB".  What would be even better is to utilize the sc tool (or something similar) to validate that RavenDB is actually installed.

Something like this:

```
sc query RavenDB
```

Comment: Agreed, I'll create a issue for this. Thanks for letting us know!

Comment: still fails on RavenDB install if port 8080 is in use